# Encoding name strings into an unique number

Tags: string, algorithm, math, text

I have a large set of names (millions in number). Each of them has a first name, an optional middle name, and a lastname. I need to encode these names into a number that uniquely represents the names. The encoding should be one-one, that is a name should be associated with only one number, and a number should be associated with only one name.

What is a smart way of encoding this? I know it is easy to tag each alphabet of the name according to its position in the alphabet set (a-> 1, b->2.. and so on) and so a name like Deepa would get -> 455161, but again here I cannot make out if the '16' is really 16 or a combination of 1 and 6.

So, I am looking for a smart way of encoding the names.

Furthermore, the encoding should be such that the number of digits in the output numeral for any name should have fixed number of digits, i.e., it should be independent of the length. Is this possible?

Thanks
Abhishek S

Comment: This won't solve the fixed length problem, but you could code each letter as 2 digits: a = 01, b = 02.... j = 10, k = 11... z = 26. What is the point of doing this conversion? There might be better solutions. Also, any hashing function you might come up with *will* have collisions at some point (ie. not strictly 1:1). Why can't you just use a database table with a sequence number as a key to which you associate a name? As new names come up, just look them up to find their key, if not there add them.

Comment: You need to explain more about your motivation for this. Naively, you can simply treat the utf-8 representation of a name as a (very large) base-256 number; translate into whatever base you prefer - but that's pretty useless. If you just need a unique identifier for each name, a database is probably your best option.

Comment: The objective is to be able to plot the names on one of the dimensions in a 3D dimension space, where the other two dimensions already are numeric in nature. So, since the names are textual in nature, we need to transform the names to numeric before plotting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do there is actually hashing (at least if you have a fixed number of digits). There are some good hashing algorithms with few collisions. Try out sha1 for example, that one is well tested and available for modern languages (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1) -- it seems to be good enough for git, so it might work for you.

There is of course a small possibility for identical hash values for two different names, but that's always the case with hashing and can be taken care of. With sha1 and such you won't have any obvious connection between names and IDs, which can be a good or a bad thing, depending on your problem.

If you really want unique ids for sure, you will need to do something like NealB suggested, create IDs yourself and connect names and IDs in a Database (you could create them randomly and check for collisions or increment them, starting at 0000000000001 or so).

(improved answer after giving it some thought and reading the first comments)

Comment: This is the best way if you want the answer to be limited to a fixed number of digits. Otherwise implement them as base 26 integers.

Comment: No, he's asking for a 1:1 mapping, which is _not_ hashing.

Comment: But calculating a value out of the names and asking for a fixed length value leaves you with hashing in my opinion (at least when the length of the names is not limited)

Comment: @NickJohnson It is true that hashes are theoretically not one to one.  But in real life the odds that you encounter one are orders of magnitude lower than the odds of a cosmic ray flipping a bit at the wrong moment.  If you don't worry about the second, why worry about the first?

Comment: @btilly I'm not saying a cryptographic hash won't work here (though it's really hard to tell what the OP actually wants to achieve) - just that your first statement "What you are trying to do there is actually hashing" is incorrect.

Comment: @NickJohnson Not my initial statement.  Look at who said what.  But for this problem I would, in fact, just use a hash and forget about it.

Answer (score 10):

To get the same width numbers, can't you just zero-pad on the left?

Some options:

1. Sort them.  Count them.  The 10th name is number 10.
2. Treat each character as a digit in a base 26 (case insensitive, no
   digits) or 52 (case significant, no digits) or 36 (case insensitive
   with digits) or 62 (case sensitive with digits) number.  Compute the
   value in an int.  EG, for a name of "abc", you'd have 0 * 26^2 + 1 *
   26^1 + 2 * 20^0.  Sometimes Chinese names may use digits to indicate tonality.
3. Use a "perfect hashing" scheme: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function
4. This one's mostly suggested in fun: use goedel numbering :).  So
   "abc" would be 2^0 * 3^1 * 5^2 - it's a product of powers of primes.
   Factoring the number gives you back the characters.  The numbers
   could get quite large though.
5. Convert to ASCII, if you aren't already using it.  Then treat each
   ordinal of a character as a digit in a base-256 numbering system. 
   So "abc" is 0*256^2 + 1*256^1 + 2*256^0.

If you need to be able to update your list of names and numbers from time to time, #2, #4 and #5 should work.  #1 and #3 would have problems.  #5 is probably the most future-proofed, though you may find you need unicode at some point.

I believe you could do unicode as a variant of #5, using powers of 2^32 instead of 2^8 == 256.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `BigInteger` for encoding arbitrary strings like this:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("some string".getBytes());
```

And for getting the string back use:

```
String str = new String(bi.toByteArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding. That is the standard approach.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a solution to a problem very similar to the one you proposed and this is what I came up with:

```
def hash_string(value):
    score = 0
    depth = 1
    for char in value:
        score += (ord(char)) * depth
        depth /= 256.
    return score
```

If you are unfamiliar with Python, here's what it does.

1. The score is initially 0 and the depth are set to 1
2. For every character add the `ord` value * the depth

   1. The `ord` function returns the UTF-8 value (0-255) for each character
   2. Then it's multiplied by the 'depth'.
3. Finally the depth is divided by 256.

Essentially, the way that it works is that the initial characters add more to the score while later characters contribute less and less. If you need an integer, multiply the end score by 2**64. Otherwise you will have a decimal value between 0-256. This encoding scheme works for binary data as well as there are only 256 possible values in a byte/char.

This method works great for smaller string values, however, for longer strings you will notice that the decimal value requires more precision than a regular double (64-bit) can provide. In Java, you can use the 'BigDecimal' and in Python use the 'decimal' module for added precision. A bonus to using this method is that the values returned are in sorted order so they can be searched 'efficiently'.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate it, if every character (plus blank, at least) will occupy a position.

Therefore ABC, which is 1,2,3 has to be translated to

```
1*(2*26+1)² + 2*(53) + 3
```

This way, you could encode arbitrary strings, but if the length of the input isn't limited (and how should it?), you aren't guaranteed to have an upper limit for the length.