# Using encoding to check if a vector contains a very long string

Tags: r, encoding

I have one long string of about 100 characters (let's call it str_1) and a vector (let's call it vec) containing about 100 000 string as below. Note that the vector below has only 3 values just for the example:

```
str_1 <- "1-3-23-4-45-6-23-1-5-6-34-4-7-8-78-6.767-56-8-56-545-4-34-23--23-34434-2-34-32432-5-4.3-2.12-12.4-12.34"
vec <- c("1-3-23-4-45-6-23-1-5-6-34-4-7-8-78-6.767-56-8-56-545-4-34-23--23-34434-2-34-32432-3-4.3-2.12-12.4-12.34",
"1-3-23-4-45-6-23-1-5-6-34-4-7-8-78-6.767-56-8-56-545-4-34-23-3-23-34434-2-34-32432-5-4.3-2.22-12.4-12.34",
"1-3-23-4-45-6-23-1-5-6-34-4-7-8-78-6.767-56-8-56-545-4-34-23-3-23-34434-2-34-32462-5-4.3-2.12-12.4-12.34")
```

I want to check is my vector contains str_1. Is it good practice to just right the following code:

```
str_1 %in% vec
```

Or is there a better way by encoding each string into a shorter value? And if yes, how?
My main concern would be to use too much memory.

Comment: maybe grep? `grep(str_1, vec)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds similar to a previous post ([Encoding name strings into an unique number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338599/encoding-name-strings-into-an-unique-number)), where the simplest solution to giving a unique identifier to each string was to use hashing. If this is also the simplest way to uniquely identify the strings in your case, it seems like it wouldn't grant much if any advantage with regard to memory, so I would just use `str_1 %in% vec` as you proposed.